# Compilation time of a compile-time binary search

Tags: c++, boost, c++20

Looking at Boost MP11's implementation of [`mp_with_index`](https://github.com/boostorg/mp11/blob/master/include/boost/mp11/detail/mp_with_index.hpp), it seems to perform a binary search to map a runtime value to a compile time constant. This seems to work fine for smaller values, like going through a variant for example. But when testing it with larger values, the compiler seems to struggle to compile the code in a timely fashion. While I didn't benchmark the compile times, running into the default time-out value of Compiler Explorer when testing 5-digit integer values seems to indicate that the compilers have to perform a lot more work than I had anticipated.

```
#include <boost/mp11/algorithm.hpp>

inline constexpr auto m = unsigned{99'999u};
inline constexpr auto n = unsigned{m - 1};

static_assert(boost::mp11::mp_with_index<m>(n,
     [](auto r){ return decltype(r)::value == n; }));
```

Since [`mp_with_index`](https://github.com/boostorg/mp11/blob/master/include/boost/mp11/detail/mp_with_index.hpp) uses a binary search algorithm, and is therefore of logarithmic time complexity, I would expect there to be at most 18 steps necessary to make the mapping happen for a 5-digit integer value. Why does it seem that the compilers require to do a lot more work than just a couple of template instantiations and integer value comparisons?

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/Y11sPjYre)

Comment: As per [Cppinsights](https://cppinsights.io/s/e175da58), it seems that there are all instantiations for 0...m. So in your case, it would lead to 100k functions. But I am unsure about exact version of boost used by cppinsights...

Comment: @Quimby It seems that CppInsights is using Boost v1.83, according to their information [page](https://cppinsights.io/version). So I would expect that the same library code is being used. CppInsights seems to only show the instantiations of the templated call-operator when passing in a generic lambda. When passing in a non-generic lambda (e.g.: `[](int){ return true; }`), there isn't much generated code being shown, and it seems to be unaffacted by the size of `m`. However, the compilation times still seem to increase dractically when increasing `m` as well, also timing out with `m=99999`.

Comment: `i` in `mp_with_index_impl_::call` is not constexpr. (Function parameters are never `constexpr`). The `if` inside it is not `if constexpr` either. (It cannot be). Consequently, both branches of the `if` are instantiated. And then both branches inside both of these instantiations are instantiated, etc, until one of the small-N specializations takes over---and then all `case` branches inside that specialization are instantiated.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI This was exactly what I had overlooked. Since the `if` branch is not marked `constexpr`, every templated entity in the body of the function will have to be instantiated, which actually creates an exponential increase in templates being instantiated. The exponential property of this logarithmic function is quite subtly tucked away in this context.

Answer (score 8):

No matter how it is done, `boost::mp11::mp_with_index<m>(f, n)` needs to instantiate `f(mp_size_t<K>{})` for `m` different values of `K`.

It doesn't matter that at most 18 branches are actually taken during the evaluation, the compiler needs to instantiate the other branches in case one of them has a failing `static_assert` or something. Imagine you had `[](auto r) requires(r != 3) { return decltype(r)::value == n; })`: this would have to fail to compile, even if `n != 3`.

So at least 100 000 templates need to be instantiated with that function call. You would expect the compile times to be directly proportional to the value of `m`. And with some light testing:

```
$ time clang++ -std=c++17 -fsyntax-only test.cpp -DMMM=1000

real    0m0.075s
user    0m0.064s
sys     0m0.009s
$ time clang++ -std=c++17 -fsyntax-only test.cpp -DMMM=10000

real    0m0.586s
user    0m0.528s
sys     0m0.050s
$ time clang++ -std=c++17 -fsyntax-only test.cpp -DMMM=100000

real    0m5.771s
user    0m5.538s
sys     0m0.230s
$ time clang++ -std=c++17 -fsyntax-only test.cpp -DMMM=1000000

real    0m58.760s
user    0m56.831s
sys     0m1.920s
```

that seems to be the case.

Comment: It didn't quite click with me yet after reading your explanation, it was not until after walking through the `mp_with_index()` code more precisely with some dummy values that it finally hit me (which, admittedly, I should have done before posting this question) and I came to the same conclusion as *n. m. could be an AI*. I think this answer could benefit by adding some comment about the non-`constexpr`ness of the `if` branch within `mp_with_index_impl_::call()` function and the implications thereof.

Comment: @303 I don't think the non-constexpr-ness is relevant here, because, while it is, it clearly doesn't prevent `constexpr` from taking arguments. They're merely not _declared_ constexpr, but their constexpr evaluation is clearly proven by the fact that it compiles. Eventually.